# C: Why CLOCKS_PER_SEC is printing 1000 when my processor speed is 3.10GHz

Tags: c, windows, clock, system-clock

My PC configuration is

Intel Core i3-2100 CPU @3.10GHz

Windows7 64 bit

But when I'm executing below code why it's printing 1000?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<time.h>
main()
{
    printf("Clock %d",CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    getch();
}
```

The actual clock speed should be around 3.1x10^12 per sec right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Clock ticks are units of time of a constant but system-specific length, as those returned by function `clock`.

It has nothing to do with the processor speed.

Answer (score 1):

see [Why is CLOCKS_PER_SEC not the actual number of clocks per second?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455905/clocks-per-sec-not-actually-clocks-per-sec)

> POSIX requires that CLOCKS_PER_SEC equals 1000000 independent of the
>   actual resolution.