# Why is the purportedly actual clocks/sec greater than 1,000,000 in many cases?

Tags: linux, unix, time

Following the question [CLOCKS_PER_SEC not actually clocks per sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455905/clocks-per-sec-not-actually-clocks-per-sec?lq=1), the same code on my multicore machine gives:

```
CLOCKS_PER_SEC = 1000000
Actual clocks per second = 89815
Actual clocks per second = 999801
Actual clocks per second = 998912
Actual clocks per second = 999911
Actual clocks per second = 1000019
Actual clocks per second = 999997
Actual clocks per second = 1000194
Actual clocks per second = 1000182
Actual clocks per second = 1000216
Actual clocks per second = 999990
```

Why is the actual clocks/sec greater than 1,000,000 in a few cases? Due to the multicore? How do we explain this?

I am running a `Linux kernel 4.0.4-202 Fedora 21` on hardware

    `Architecture:          x86_64
    CPU(s):                8
    On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
    Thread(s) per core:    2
    Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4910MQ CPU @ 2.90GHz
    CPU MHz:               967.195
    CPU max MHz:           3900.0000
    CPU min MHz:           800.0000`

Comment: What hardware and OS are you running?

Comment: hardware and OS details updated in question

Answer (score 0):

On a busy system, the running test program isn't going to be granted all CPU power.

There is then no guarantee for it not to be suspended for some period of time. If the turnover from one second to the next happen when the process is waiting for a CPU, the next `clock()` call will happen late, thus the "more than one second" delta.

Alternatively, the variation you see might be due to some rounding happening in the `clock()` call.

In any case, I do not reproduce it on various systems, either single or multi-core.